# ¿Cómo traducir "sweet spot" al español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

"[Sweet spot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_spot_(sports))" es un término del ámbito del deporte que viene a ser el punto donde debes golpear o ejercer mayor esfuerzo para conseguir mejores resultados.

> The sweet spot is **a place** where a combination of factors results in a maximum response for a given amount of effort. In tennis, squash, [..] a given swing will result in a more powerful hit if the ball strikes the racket, bat or club on the latter's **sweet spot**.
>
> Source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_spot_(sports))

El "sweet spot" no es solo un punto físico donde ejercer mayor fuerza. A veces se usa en sentido abstracto. Si seguimos en el ámbito del deporte, pero hablamos de entrenamiento, el *sweet spot* sería por ejemplo el número de horas que puedes entrenar para que el ejercicio te rinda sin estresar a tu cuerpo. El *sweet spot* podría ser también el número de horas que puedes estudiar al día, o el número de minutos que puede durar una sesión de estudio antes de que tu cerebro diga "no puedo más" y el resto de horas sean simplemente tiempo perdido enfrente del libro.

Otro ejemplo, en su libro "[The Happiest Toddler in the Block](https://janielyoung.com/2013/03/20/happiest-toddler-on-the-block-what-works-and-what-doesnt/)" el Dr. Karp dice que, por ejemplo, cuando tu niño llora debes demostrar que entiendes sus sentimientos, básicamente repitiendo lo que dice y en una intensidad parecida, para alcanzar su *sweet spot*.

> Basically you mirror their feelings in short, repetitive phrasing. Like if T was crying to be picked up, instead of saying “mommy can’t pick you up because her hands are covered in turtle slime and I don’t want you to get salmonella and die,” I would say: “Tenny sad! Tenny wants up now now now!”
>
> [...] You supposed to hit the **“sweet spot”** of emotional intensity with your words.

Si fuera sólo un punto físico, estaría tentado de proponer traducirlo como "punto de apoyo", pero esto no vale en todos los casos (por ejemplo, "*el punto de apoyo* donde debes golpear la bola de golf con el palo" queda un poco raro). Podría decir "el punto justo", que tiene un poco más las connotaciones de "haber acertado en la diana", pero aunque esto pueda ser válido para algunos de los ejemplos donde debes saber "dónde golpear" no sería tan valido para otros, como en los ejemplos de entrenamiento o estudio.

¿Cómo se puede traducir "sweet spot" al español?

Comment: ¿Qué tal "punto/lugar/nivel ideal"? Según la disciplina o ámbito de que se trate, se podría optar por un sustantivo u otro. En cuanto al adjetivo, parecería adaptarse a todos los casos, ¿no?

Answer (score 3):

Pues parece ser que el término traducido literal, **"punto dulce"**, es usado en una variedad de sentidos. Incluso tenemos un caso en el CREA:

> *EL REAL MADRID, QUE PARECE haber perdido el punto dulce de juego de anteriores jornadas, conoció el contrasentido de fortalecer sus aspiraciones al título en un partido en el que mostró su peor cara.*
>
> [Albert Turro, "La Vanguardia", 03/04/1995](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=030317%5C008%5CC000O03032017084255536.1220.1216&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20punto%20dulce%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCREA%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto0)

También en webs específicas sobre béisbol y tenis se usa:

> [Punto Dulce (sweetspot)](http://www.tenniswarehouse-europe.com/lc/RacquetStringTerms.html?lang=es): Área de una raqueta encordada que proporciona el mayor y mejor retorno de energía (potencia) y la mejor precisión con el menor impacto o vibración posible.
>
> [El punto dulce](http://www.fismec.com/lectura_dulce) de una raqueta de tenis o de un bate de beisbol es el lugar donde el impacto de la pelota produce el mínimo de vibraciones en la raqueta o el bate. Si golpeas una pelota con el punto dulce saldrá despedida con más rapidez y llegara más lejos.
>
> Envolver cinta alrededor del [punto dulce](http://muyfitness.com/efectos-cinta-bates-info_30347/) de un bate de béisbol de madera puede aumentar la vida útil [...].

E incluso referido a las emociones:

> Los hallazgos de Lo sugieren que existe un [punto dulce](https://es.insider.pro/investment/2016-09-06/los-cientificos-han-decidido-controlar-las-emociones-de-los-operadores/) para el compromiso emocional: si es demasiado grande, la persona se vuelve demasiado agresiva o temerosa; si es demasiado pequeño, la persona no se involucra lo suficiente como para hacer las cosas bien.

Comment: Al menos tres de esos artículos son traducciones de originales en inglés, por lo que podría decirse que quien los tradujo se limitó a traducir la expresión literalmente en vez de emplear otra, más o menos equivalente y con más sentido en español.

Comment: @JMVanPelt bueno, es una forma como cualquier otra de introducir neologismos en el español. Si no hay un término previo, y "punto dulce" acaba siendo usado ampliamente, terminará siendo aceptado.

Comment: Yo estoy de acuerdo con los dos. Suena a traducción directa de un anglicismo, pero si no hay otro término será el que se termine usando. +1 de momento y si nadie propone nada mejor en unos días... pues aceptaré esta respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Centro de percusión

Explicación física completa: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4l26nVKmShU

Aplicado al deporte: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szQOn2ObP7M

Comment: Eso, por supuesto, sólo para el "sweet spot" de una raqueta o un bate. Si no... punto óptimo.

Answer (score 1):

En español mexicano, "sweet spot" podría traducirse como "blanco" en ciertos contextos.

Por ejemplo:

"You hit the sweet spot" = "Le diste al blanco".

"Punto justo" suena bien también.

"Punto dulce" suena raro y nunca en mi vida lo he escuchado.